# Glassfish Security Realms base on URL

Tags: java, spring, security, glassfish

I'm working on an RESTFul API that need to authenticate users on different realms based on the URL called. For example, if you call /service1 you need to be authenticated on a JDBCRealm, but if you call /service2, you need to be authenticated on a LDAPRealm.

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to configure (database or config file) which url uses which realm. This configuration wouldn't require a redeployment of my war if possible.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2 with Jersey and Spring 3.0.5


Thank you, have a nice day!

--
Samuel Dionne

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate layer for it so that it forwards the request to the proper device per authentication.  Actually this is a good use case for the IBM DataPower device if you are a big enterprise, if not a simple proxy server can do the job for you.